# How to set routing type ActiveMQ Artemis from client

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to follow the hello world example. With regular ActiveMQ it works, but ActiveMQ Artemis is giving me headaches. I guess there is some configuration I am not doing correctly. The Address is made, but is it made using Multicast routing. I think I need Unicast (queue routing).

The below snippet does not work for the artemis version of ActiveMQ. Is it possible what I am trying to do? I would like to auto-create a durable Queue.

```
public class SimpleAmqpTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestHelloWorld()
        {
            Address address = new Address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
            Connection connection = await Connection.Factory.CreateAsync(address);
            Session session = new Session(connection);

            Message message = new Message("Hello AMQP");

            var target = new Target
            {
                Address = "simple-queue",
                Durable = 1,
            };

            SenderLink sender = new SenderLink(session, "sender-link", target, null);
            await sender.SendAsync(message);

            ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, "receiver-link", "simple-queue");
            message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync();
            receiver.Accept(message);

            await sender.CloseAsync();
            await receiver.CloseAsync();
            await session.CloseAsync();
            await connection.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out what I was doing wrong, as Amqp does not have the configuration of queues and topics, it can be defined in the Capabilities. For some reason Artemis creates topics by default (multicast). If you need AnyCast you can specify your need using `Capabilities = new Symbol[] { new Symbol("queue") }`. For the full test fact:

```
public async Task TestHelloWorld()
        {
            //strange, works using regular activeMQ and the amqp test broker from here: http://azure.github.io/amqpnetlite/articles/hello_amqp.html
            //but this does not work in ActiveMQ Artemis
            Address address = new Address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
            Connection connection = await Connection.Factory.CreateAsync(address);
            Session session = new Session(connection);

            Message message = new Message("Hello AMQP");

            Target target = new Target
            {
                Address = "q1",
                Capabilities = new Symbol[] { new Symbol("queue") }
            };

            SenderLink sender = new SenderLink(session, "sender-link", target, null);
            sender.Send(message);

            Source source = new Source
            {
                Address = "q1",
                Capabilities = new Symbol[] { new Symbol("queue") }
            };

            ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, "receiver-link", source, null);
            message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync();
            receiver.Accept(message);

            await sender.CloseAsync();
            await receiver.CloseAsync();
            await session.CloseAsync();
            await connection.CloseAsync();
        }
```

Comment: The routing type used for auto-created addresses and queues can be controlled via the `default-queue-routing-type` and `default-address-routing-type` `address-setting` elements. These both default to `multicast`. If you don't want to change your AMQP clients you can change these for the relevant addresses to `anycast`.

Comment: I had to dig through source code on this one. Yes this does in fact work and the settings mentioned can be used to set the defaults.